# Subversion and Stats

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I wanted to see how productive I had been over a 6 month period is there any commands or tools I can run over a SVN repo to get this kind of information? by user (so I can filter to myself)

I would like to see things like
lines committed by me
lines removed by me
some kind of churn stat
etc...

Looking for an easy method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.statsvn.org/ can produce a lot of various statistics.